# When is the Redo-port called with new variables in Trace/0 and when not?

Tags: prolog, choice-point

During my implementation of the [Adventure game in Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/index.php) I was wondering when the redo-port is called with new variables during backtracking and when it is called with the same ones?

For example, I have the following knowledge base:

```
location(desk,office).
location(apple,kitchen).
location(flashlight,desk).
location('washing machine',cellar).
location(nani,'washing machine').
location(broccoli,kitchen).
location(crackers,kitchen).
location(computer,office).

door(office,hall).
door(kitchen,office).
door(hall,'dining room').
door(kitchen,cellar).
door('dining room',kitchen).
```

When tracing the query `?-(location(X,Y),door(kitchen,Y)).` I get this:

```
   Call: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(desk, office) ? creep
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep
X = desk,
Y = office ;
   Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep      <==== 1
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep
   Redo: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(apple, kitchen) ? creep
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen) ? creep
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen) ? creep
   Redo: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(flashlight, desk) ? creep
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, desk) ? creep
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, desk) ? creep
   Redo: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location('washing machine', cellar) ? creep
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, cellar) ? creep
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, cellar) ? creep
X = 'washing machine',
Y = cellar ;
   Redo: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep    <==== 2
   Exit: (9) location(nani, 'washing machine') ? creep
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, 'washing machine') ? creep
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, 'washing machine') ? creep
   Redo: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(broccoli, kitchen) ? creep
```

```
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen) ? creep
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen) ? creep
   Redo: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(crackers, kitchen) ? creep
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen) ? creep
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen) ? creep
   Redo: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(computer, office) ? creep
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep
X = computer,
Y = office ;
   Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep    <==== 3
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep
false.
```

I understand how the binding of the variables works, but I do not understand why Prolog returns

`Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep`    <==== 1
`Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep`    <==== 3

after finding the first solution (and the same for the last solution),

while it immediately looks for a new binding of X and Y after the second solution

`Redo: (9) location(_7998, _8000) ? creep`    <==== 2

Why does it not immediately continue to look for a new binding of X and Y after the first and last solution, instead of resorting to

`Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office) ? creep`    <==== 3

(which fails anyway)?

(I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192069/too-much-backtracking-why-is-there-a-redo-here), but unfortunately my reputation does not allow me to comment over there and I think this particular issue does not have to do with my Prolog version (as I tried it with SWI-Prolog and GNUProlog))

Thanks in advance for offering any clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For some reason I completely missed that it was possible to edit the title of your question as well. Is it better now, in your opinion, to take this question to a comment on the aforementioned question, or does it deserve a separate question? It is a bit hard for a beginner to gain insight in how closely related questions are.

Comment: As a beginner just ask a new question if you are not sure. If someone feels it is  a duplicate they will let you know and should mark it as a duplicate. IIRC if three people vote it as the same duplicate it will get marked as one, or if someone has enough rep they can do it by themselves.

Comment: Of interest: [Simple Queries](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a3simple.php)

Comment: I created the tag `choice-point` and added some references there that might help explain choice points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer makes use of SWI-Prolog.

The first thing that can help when using trace for the first time is to make all of the ports [visible](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=visible/1). By default the unify port is not visible but can be made visible with

```
?- visible(+unify).
```

Now since this is such a short running query, instead of having to press the space bar for each port, we can disable the [leashing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=leash/1) of the leashed ports with

```
?- leash(-call).
?- leash(-exit).
?- leash(-redo).
?- leash(-fail).
```

Now if you turn on trace and run the query

```
?- trace.
[trace] ?- (location(X,Y),door(kitchen,Y)).
```

you will not have to press the space bar expect for answers.

Doing so will return

```
   Call: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(desk, office)
   Exit: (9) location(desk, office)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Unify: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, office)
X = desk,
Y = office ;
   Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(apple, kitchen)
   Exit: (9) location(apple, kitchen)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(flashlight, desk)
   Exit: (9) location(flashlight, desk)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, desk)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, desk)
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location('washing machine', cellar)
   Exit: (9) location('washing machine', cellar)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, cellar)
   Unify: (9) door(kitchen, cellar)
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, cellar)
X = 'washing machine',
Y = cellar ;
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(nani, 'washing machine')
   Exit: (9) location(nani, 'washing machine')
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, 'washing machine')
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, 'washing machine')
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(broccoli, kitchen)
   Exit: (9) location(broccoli, kitchen)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(crackers, kitchen)
   Exit: (9) location(crackers, kitchen)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(computer, office)
   Exit: (9) location(computer, office)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Unify: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, office)
X = computer,
Y = office ;
   Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, office)
false.
```

which now has the **Unify** ports visible.

Since this is such a short query I will comment the significant lines of the trace and that in turn should answer your questions.

```
   % location fact 1: location(desk, office) -------------------------
   % First predicate of query - location(X,Y)

   % The location facts are matched in the order of the source code
   % Since the code is looking for location(X,Y)
   % it matches location fact 1: location(desk, office)
   % Since there are more location facts like location(X, Y),
   % e.g.
   %   location(apple,kitchen).
   %   location(flashlight,desk).
   %   location('washing machine',cellar).
   %   location(nani,'washing machine').
   %   location(broccoli,kitchen).
   %   location(crackers,kitchen).
   %   location(computer,office).
   % a choice point is generated
   % choice point: location 1
   Call: (9) location(_9632, _9634)

   % Unifies with first location fact.
   % X binds with desk
   % Y binds with office
   Unify: (9) location(desk, office)

   Exit: (9) location(desk, office)

   % Second predicate of query - door(kitchen,Y)).
   % Y is bound with office
   % The door facts are matched in the order of the source code
   % Since the code is only looking for door(kitchen,office)
   % it matches door fact 2: door(kitchen,office)
   % Since there are more door facts like door(kitchen,Y),
   % e.g.
   %    door(kitchen,cellar).
   % a choice point is generated
   % choice point: door 1
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, office)

   % Since there is a door(kitchen, office) fact
   % unify with second predicate
   Unify: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   % No more predicates in the query so return result.
X = desk,
Y = office ;

   % Remember choice point: door 1
   % Use the second predicate
   % on the remaining door facts like door(kitchen,Y)
   % e.g.
   %    door(kitchen,cellar).
   Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office)

   % There are no more door facts that unify with door(kitchen, office)
   % so fail.
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, office)

   % Since the second predicate failed,
   % go back to the first predicate location(X,Y)
   % location fact 2: location(apple, kitchen) -----------------------

   % Remember choice point: location 1
   % Use the first predicate
   % on the remaining location facts like location(X,Y)
   % e.g.
   %   location(apple,kitchen).
   %   location(flashlight,desk).
   %   location('washing machine',cellar).
   %   location(nani,'washing machine').
   %   location(broccoli,kitchen).
   %   location(crackers,kitchen).
   %   location(computer,office).
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)

   % The second fact unifies with the first predicate location(X,Y)
   % X binds with apple
   % Y binds with kitchen
   Unify: (9) location(apple, kitchen)
   Exit: (9) location(apple, kitchen)

   % Second predicate of query - door(kitchen,Y)).
   % Y is bound with kitchen
   % The door facts are matched in the order of the source code
   % Since the code is only looking for door(kitchen,kitchen)
   % it matches none of the door facts
   % and since it checked all of the door facts
   % no choice point was generated.
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)

   % There is no door(kitchen, kitchen) fact so fail.
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)

   % location fact 3: location(flashlight, desk) ---------------------
   % Remember choice point: location 1
   % Use the first predicate
   % on the remaining location facts like location(X,Y)
   % e.g.
   %   location(flashlight,desk).
   %   location('washing machine',cellar).
   %   location(nani,'washing machine').
   %   location(broccoli,kitchen).
   %   location(crackers,kitchen).
   %   location(computer,office).
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(flashlight, desk)
   Exit: (9) location(flashlight, desk)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, desk)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, desk)

   % Since the second predicate failed,
   % go back to the first predicate location(X,Y)
   % location fact 4: location('washing machine', cellar)  -----------
   % Remember choice point: location 1
   % Use the first predicate
   % on the remaining location facts like location(X,Y)
   % e.g.
   %   location('washing machine',cellar).
   %   location(nani,'washing machine').
   %   location(broccoli,kitchen).
   %   location(crackers,kitchen).
   %   location(computer,office).
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)

   % The forth fact unifies with the first predicate location(X,Y)
   % X binds with 'washing machine'
   % Y binds with cellar
   Unify: (9) location('washing machine', cellar)

   Exit: (9) location('washing machine', cellar)

   % Second predicate of query - door(kitchen,Y)).
   % Y is bound with cellar
   % The door facts are matched in the order of the source code
   % Since the code is only looking for door(kitchen,cellar)
   % it matches door fact 4: door(kitchen,cellar)
   % Since there are NO more door facts like door(kitchen,Y),
   % NO choice point is generated
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, cellar)

   % There is a door(kitchen, cellar) fact so unify.
   Unify: (9) door(kitchen, cellar)
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, cellar)
   % No more predicates in the query so return result.
X = 'washing machine',
Y = cellar ;

   % location fact 5: location(nani, 'washing machine') --------------
   % Remember choice point: location 1
   % Use the first predicate
   % on the remaining location facts like location(X,Y)
   % e.g.
   %   location(nani,'washing machine').
   %   location(broccoli,kitchen).
   %   location(crackers,kitchen).
   %   location(computer,office).
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(nani, 'washing machine')
   Exit: (9) location(nani, 'washing machine')
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, 'washing machine')
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, 'washing machine')

   % location fact 6: location(broccoli, kitchen) --------------------
   % Remember choice point: location 1
   % Use the first predicate
   % on the remaining location facts like location(X,Y)
   % e.g.
   %   location(broccoli,kitchen).
   %   location(crackers,kitchen).
   %   location(computer,office).
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(broccoli, kitchen)
   Exit: (9) location(broccoli, kitchen)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)

   % location fact 7: location(crackers, kitchen) --------------------
   % Remember choice point: location 1
   % Use the first predicate
   % on the remaining location facts like location(X,Y)
   % e.g.
   %   location(crackers,kitchen).
   %   location(computer,office).
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)
   Unify: (9) location(crackers, kitchen)
   Exit: (9) location(crackers, kitchen)
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, kitchen)

   % Since the second predicate failed,
   % go back to the first predicate location(X,Y)
   % location fact 8: location(computer, office) ---------------------
   % Remember choice point: location 1
   % Use the first predicate
   % on the remaining location facts like location(X,Y)
   % e.g.
   %   location(computer,office).
   Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)

   % The last fact unifies with the first predicate location(X,Y)
   % X binds with computer
   % Y binds with office
   Unify: (9) location(computer, office)
   Exit: (9) location(computer, office)

   % Second predicate of query - door(kitchen,Y)).
   % Y is bound with office
   % The door facts are matched in the order of the source code
   % Since the code is only looking for door(kitchen,office)
   % it matches door fact 2: door(kitchen,office)
   % Since there are more door facts like door(kitchen,Y),
   % e.g.
   %    door(kitchen,cellar).
   % a choice point is generated
   % choice point: door 2
   Call: (9) door(kitchen, office)

   % Since there is a door(kitchen, office) fact
   % unify with second predicate
   Unify: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   Exit: (9) door(kitchen, office)
   % No more predicates in the query so return result.
X = computer,
Y = office ;
   % Remember choice point: door 2
   % Use the second predicate
   % on the remaining door facts like door(kitchen,Y)
   % e.g.
   %    door(kitchen,cellar).
   Redo: (9) door(kitchen, office)

   % There are no more door facts that unify with door(kitchen, office)
   % so fail.
   Fail: (9) door(kitchen, office)

   % There are no more location facts so end the query.
false.
```

### Supplement

When I created the answer it was in a text editor that can do syntax highlight for Prolog code, and to help me keep things straight I had three panes open for comparing. One pane had the location and door rules. One pane had a comment, and the third pane had a similar comment. As I moved down the code I kept updating the comments in the third pane to match similar comment in the second pane while checking against the facts in the first pane. I note this because it is probably a better way to understand the comments than reading them from this answer as posted.

The editor is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and for highlighting Prolog the [Prolog extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.prolog) is installed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. I still do not seem to get, however, why there is nothing after the second solution along the lines of `Redo: (9) door(kitchen, cellar)` and then `Fail: (9) door(kitchen, cellar)` (as is the case after the first and third solution) before we get to `Redo: (9) location(_9632, _9634)`? There is still the remaining door fact `door('dining room',kitchen).`, no? To me it seems like something is skipped after the second solution, but I am probably just missing something.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I understand correctly, there is no such `Redo` after the second solution, because there is no predicate of the form `door(kitchen,Y)` left in the code after it has found `door(kitchen,cellar)`?

Comment: Thank you for including a screenshot of your editor; it makes things clearer indeed. Is there perhaps an IDE for Prolog that you could recommend as well?

Comment: Could I still elaborate on my question by editing it, or should I then create a new topic? I thought I understood the whole thing about choice points and redo's but I have a few lines of Prolog where the 'theory' I tried to give a couple of comments above does not seem to hold.

Comment: @milanv After accepting an answer it is better to start a new question. Remember that is not just you and I reading this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I posted a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425538/choice-points-and-redos-in-prolog .

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog FAQ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.prolog/8m5lIFd82pQ) - Related to Prolog IDEs - See question `15. How do I edit Prolog code? `

Answer (score 2):

This is just a comment posted as a answer because it has a picture.

If you use the graphical debugger you can see when choice points are created.

```
?- gtrace.
true.

[trace] ?- (location(X,Y),door(kitchen,Y)).
```

In the following image of the debugger I highlighted the choice point with a green rectangle.

To exit out of trace mode in top-level enter `nodebug`.

```
[trace] ?- nodebug.
true.

?-
```

Note: It is the choice points that lead to using the redo port.
Note: Another way to debug prolog is via use of [failure slice](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/failure-slice/info). Also read questions [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failure-slice) with failure slice

[image]