# Prolog - Explain trace steps in English

Tags: prolog, trace, unification

```
plays(alice, leadguitar).
plays(noah, drums).
plays(mike, leadguitar).
plays(mike, drums).
plays(katie, baseguitar).
plays(drew, leadguitar).
plays(drew, baseguitar).

duetwith(Person1,Person2):- 
    plays(Person1,L),
    plays(Person2,L), 
    Person1 \= Person2.
```

I write a new rule called combo that determines whether or not three people can make a combo with a drummer, a base guitar, and a lead guitar.

```
combo(Person1,Person2,Person3):- 
    plays(Person1,X), 
    plays(Person2,Y), 
    plays(Person3,Z), 
    X \= Y, 
    Y \= Z, 
    X\=Z.
```

Can drew, alice, and mike make a combo?

```
combo(mike,alice,drew).
```

true so the answer is yes they can make a combo.

I need help understanding the steps the program takes to answer the above query in prolog. Any help with a list of steps is greatly appreciated so I can gain a deeper understanding of each step Prolog takes.

Here is an example of a list of steps Prolog takes for a different example just to give an idea of what I am looking for.

In the case of `talkswith(bob,allen)`, the engine took the following steps:

1. In

   talkswith(Person1,Person2):- 
       speaks(Person1,L),
       speaks(Person2,L), 
       Person1 \= Person2.

replace every occurrence of `Person1` with `bob` and `Person2` with `allen` to get

```
talkswith(bob,allen) :- 
    speaks(bob,L),
    speaks(allen,L),
    bob \= allen.
```

2. Let’s see if we can find a value for L that makes the right side true.  Start with `speaks(bob,L).`  What can L be?  Here are our facts:

   1. speaks(allen, russian).
   2. speaks(bob, english).
   3. speaks(mary, russian).
   4. speaks(mary, english).
3. In fact 1, the first slot isn’t bob, so that won’t work.  In fact 2, the first slot is bob, so let’s try `L = english`in `speaks(allen,L), bob \= allen.`  Now we are asking  `speaks(allen,english), bob\= allen.`
4. Back to the knowledge base.  Does `speaks(allen,english)` match a fact?  Not fact 1, not fact 2, not fact 3, not fact 4.  This fails.
5. Now we back up to step 2.  Fact 2 didn’t work out, so let’s try fact 3.  No, that isn’t bob.  Fact 4 isn’t bob either.  We can’t find a value for L that works, so the search failed.

Comment: You can use `trace.`, then Prolog will print all the steps it does to obtain a result.

Comment: yes trace is somewhat helpful but I need to translate that into the form of the example above with the steps written out and explained in plain english.

Comment: Of interest: [When is the Redo-port called with new variables in Trace/0 and when not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393321/1243762)

Comment: *Yes trace is somewhat helpful but I need to translate that into the form of the example above with the steps written out and explained in plain english*. Are you having trouble understanding the trace? What aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> replace every occurrence of Person1 with bob

Prolog uses [syntactic unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Syntactic_unification_of_first-order_terms) which never does replacement. A [free variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) can only be bound once to a value. If it looks like a variable is being changed more than once, it is not. There can be many [stack frames](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch10s07.html) and for each stack frame a new set of variables can be created.

---

> Trace is somewhat helpful but I need to translate that into the form of the example above with the steps written out and explained in plain English.

For these facts

```
plays(alice, leadguitar).
plays(noah, drums).
plays(mike, leadguitar).
plays(mike, drums).
plays(katie, baseguitar).
plays(drew, leadguitar).
plays(drew, baseguitar).
```

and this predicate

```
combo(Person1,Person2,Person3):- 
    plays(Person1,X), 
    plays(Person2,Y), 
    plays(Person3,Z), 
    X \= Y, 
    Y \= Z, 
    X\=Z.
```

and this query

```
combo(mike,alice,drew).
```

First read SWI-Prolog [Debugging and Tracing Programs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger)

Run the query with trace, unify port enabled and leashing off.

```
?- visible(+unify).
true.

?- leash(-all).
true.

?- trace.
true.

[trace] ?- combo(mike,alice,drew).
   Call: (8) combo(mike, alice, drew)
   Unify: (8) combo(mike, alice, drew)
   Call: (9) plays(mike, _7040)
   Unify: (9) plays(mike, leadguitar)
   Exit: (9) plays(mike, leadguitar)
   Call: (9) plays(alice, _7040)
   Unify: (9) plays(alice, leadguitar)
   Exit: (9) plays(alice, leadguitar)
   Call: (9) plays(drew, _7040)
   Unify: (9) plays(drew, leadguitar)
   Exit: (9) plays(drew, leadguitar)
   Call: (9) leadguitar\=leadguitar
   Fail: (9) leadguitar\=leadguitar
   Redo: (9) plays(drew, _7040)
   Unify: (9) plays(drew, baseguitar)
   Exit: (9) plays(drew, baseguitar)
   Call: (9) leadguitar\=leadguitar
   Fail: (9) leadguitar\=leadguitar
   Redo: (9) plays(mike, _7040)
   Unify: (9) plays(mike, drums)
   Exit: (9) plays(mike, drums)
   Call: (9) plays(alice, _7040)
   Unify: (9) plays(alice, leadguitar)
   Exit: (9) plays(alice, leadguitar)
   Call: (9) plays(drew, _7040)
   Unify: (9) plays(drew, leadguitar)
   Exit: (9) plays(drew, leadguitar)
   Call: (9) drums\=leadguitar
   Exit: (9) drums\=leadguitar
   Call: (9) leadguitar\=leadguitar
   Fail: (9) leadguitar\=leadguitar
   Redo: (9) plays(drew, _7040)
   Unify: (9) plays(drew, baseguitar)
   Exit: (9) plays(drew, baseguitar)
   Call: (9) drums\=leadguitar
   Exit: (9) drums\=leadguitar
   Call: (9) leadguitar\=baseguitar
   Exit: (9) leadguitar\=baseguitar
   Call: (9) drums\=baseguitar
   Exit: (9) drums\=baseguitar
   Exit: (8) combo(mike, alice, drew)
true.
```

---

```
Call: (8) combo(mike, alice, drew)
```

Prolog looks for a predicate that matches the query. When Prolog looks for a predicate it searches by predicate name, in this case `combo`, and arity, in this case `3` and finds only one predicate with one clause. Prolog also searches for predicates in the order they appear in the source code. There is more to it (indexing) but that level of detail is not needed to explain this simple query.

---

```
Unify: (8) combo(mike, alice, drew)
```

Once Prolog has found a clause/fact based on predicate name and arity it checks that the query and head of the clause or fact can be unified.

`mike` unifies with `Person1`. `Person1` is now bound to `mike`.
`alice` unifies with `Person2`. `Person2` is now bound to `alice`.
`drew` unifies with `Person3`. `Person3` is now bound to `drew`.

---

```
Call: (9) plays(mike, _7040)
```

If the previous statement unifies, then the next statement is called. Each statement is a query in itself. So running the query `plays(mike,X).` as a stand alone query is the same as this statement in the clause. There are many facts for `plays/2` and two of them match `plays(mike,X).` Prolog uses the first one it finds, however since there are more than one, a choice point is made. We will call this specific choice point `plays(mike,X) - cp1` and refer back a specific choice point when a corresponding REDO is encountered.

---

```
Unify: (9) plays(mike, leadguitar)
```

Once Prolog has found a clause/fact based on predicate name and arity it checks that the query and head of the clause can be unified.

`plays` unifies with `plays`
`mike` unifies with `mike`
`_7040` unifies with `leadguitar`. `_7040` is bound to `leadguitar`.

---

```
Exit: (9) plays(mike, leadguitar)
```

This is just completing the ports of the Prolog [box model](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/node48.html). It shows the result of `Call: (9) plays(mike, _7040)`.  No unification takes place for this statement.

---

```
Call: (9) plays(alice, _7040)
Unify: (9) plays(alice, leadguitar)
Exit: (9) plays(alice, leadguitar)
```

Same pattern for `alice`. Alice has only one fact so not choice points generated for her.

---

```
Call: (9) plays(drew, _7040)
Unify: (9) plays(drew, leadguitar)
Exit: (9) plays(drew, leadguitar)
```

Same pattern for `drew`. Since drew has two facts for `plays(drew,X).` a choice point is generated. `plays(drew,X) - cp1`

---

```
Call: (9) leadguitar\=leadguitar
```

This is the fourth statement `X \= Y` with `X` is bound to `leadguitar` and `Y` is bound to `leadguitar`

---

```
Fail: (9) leadguitar\=leadguitar
```

Since `leadguitar` is not different from `leadguitar` this query fails. Upon failure Prolog goes back to the last choice point (Redo) and tries to find another solution.

---

```
Redo: (9) plays(drew, _7040)
```

Remember the last choice point created, `plays(drew,X) - cp1`. Since something failed the query is tried with another possible solution. Since the first choice point for `plays(drew,X)` failed with `X` being `leadguitar`, the second fact is used, `plays(drew,baseguitar).`

---

```
Unify: (9) plays(drew, baseguitar)
```

Just shows that the second fact for `plays(drew,X)` is being used.

---

```
Exit: (9) plays(drew, baseguitar)
```

It shows the result of `Redo: (9) plays(drew, _7040)`.

---

The remainder is just more copy/paste of what has been done already and changing out the statements, variables, bound values, etc.

---

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393321/1243762) is similar, but has more detail.

---

Of note is this question

> I write a new rule called combo that determines whether or not three people can make a combo with a drummer, a base guitar, and a lead guitar.

is not answered by this query

```
combo(Person1,Person2,Person3):- 
    plays(Person1,X), 
    plays(Person2,Y), 
    plays(Person3,Z), 
    X \= Y, 
    Y \= Z, 
    X\=Z.
```

because if these facts are added

```
plays(alice, flute).
plays(noah, cello).
plays(mike, trumpet).
```

this query

```
?- combo(alice,noah,mike).
true ;
true .
```

says true but `alice`, `noah` and `mike` are not playing the leadguitar, drums, and baseguitar.

Comment: i should have worded it in a clearer manner. Three people can make a combo as long as they each play different instruments.

Comment: I’m not sure if you are directing that comment at myself, but I upvoted all of the comments and the answer

Comment: Also are you saying my Combo query is written incorrectly ?